# Нужно ли выделять запятыми "для начала" в стихотворной строчке?

Tags: авторская-пунктуация

Им от соблазнов в помощь для начала воздвигнем горы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Возможны варианты, но лучше обойтись без обособления:

***Им от соблазнов в помощь** / для начала воздвигнем гОры.*

Небольшая произносительная пауза, ударение уходит в конец предложения. Основное содержание во второй части сообщения.

2. Оборот "им от соблазнов в помощь" обособляется **факультативно**. При обособлении будет такая расстановка ударений:

***Им от соблАзнов в помощь**, // для начала воздвигнем гОры.*

Ударением выделена **первая** часть предложения, **подчеркнутая** пауза.

Соответственно, **автор** может выбрать подходящий по тексту вариант.